# Difference between passing by a list and passing by *args

Tags: python

I learnt that the non-keyword arguments *args allow us to take in variable number of inputs, but we can also do that by passing a list, can someone help illustrate the difference?

```
args = [1, 2, 3]

def myfunc1(args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)

myfunc1(args)

def myfunc2(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)

myfunc2(*args)
```

What confuses me is that I can also pass a list containing **multiple arguments** instead of *args (in this case just some diff in grammar), can they be used alternatively or *args is industry standard so we follow this?

Comment: One is a single argument, the other is multiple arguments? I'm not sure I understand what you want to be shown.

Comment: All you have shown is that `*args` is seen as an iterable inside the function.

Comment: `myfunc1([1, 2, 3, 4])` versus `myfunc2(1, 2, 3, 4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` on a function call does opposite to what it does in a definition - if you use both, you will not notice any new behaviour, because they basicly do the inverse - one unpacks a list into separate arguments, other packs them back into a list.
Consider the following code:

```
args = [1, 2, 3]
arg1 = 4
arg2 = 5
arg3 = 6

def myfunc1(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print(arg1)
    print(arg2)
    print(arg3)

myfunc1(*args) # list gets unpacked into 3 separate arguments

def myfunc2(*args): # packs all the arguments into a single list
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)

myfunc2(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Comment: it's clear that simply using List cannot replace *args in your examples (unpacking or packing), many thanks :)